# Suddenly can't open text file in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Not sure what happened, but I was editing this text file and all of the sudden, IntelliJ couldn't figure out how to open it anymore.

When I looked, I found another one in the same directory that has a "?" on it and I can't open it either. The other ones open just fine.

[image]

Things I've tried:
Invalidating cache and restart
Rebooting
Opening file in gVim (worked)

Tried googling, but didn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be something in these files that are preventing IntelliJ from auto-detecting the type of file. I had to explicitly define these files as text in Settings | Editor | File Types to get it to open with the text editor.

Next step is to figure out why these files aren't auto detecting.